# Serving stored user images through authenticated rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using a Rails 4 api server. There are some stored user images on production server storage. Only authenticated and authorised users should be able to view their respective images.

I have authentication and authorisation modules sorted out in my APIs. However, what would be the way to serve these assets through API other than putting them in asset pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to this, I used regular Rails APIs with authentication and authorisation.
The show controller method serves the file like this:

```
send_file file_path_on_server, disposition: 'inline'
```